# Prove that for all x $\in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that the number a(n) := $x^2$ + 4x + 3 has a non-trivial divisor

Tags: prime-numbers, induction, divisibility

Task: Prove

Prove that for all x $\in \mathbb{N}$ it holds that the number a(n) := $x^2$ + 4x + 3  has a non-trivial divisor.

Non-trivial divisor: A non-trivial divisor of the number a is a natural number n with n!= 1 and n != a, so that a is multiple of n.

I tried to prove it with induction, but I am not quite able to finish the proof.

What I have so far:

Base case: a(1) = 2 + 4 + 3 = 8; 8 = 4 * 2, so this holds

Hypothesis: a(x) = $x^2$ + 4x + 3 = y * n with n != 1 and n != a holds

Now we have to show that a(x+1) holds:

a(x+1) = $(x+1)^2$ + 4(x+1) + 3 = $x^2$ + 2x + 1 + 4x + 4 + 3 =

= $x^2$ + 6x + 8

Now I can write: $x^2$ + 6x + 8 = ($x^2$ + 4x + 3) + (2x +5)

and substitute ($x^2$ + 4x + 3) with y * n from the hypothesis

Then I get: y * x + 2x + 5

And here I am stuck, I do not know how to continue.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: just factor the quadratic.

Comment: "Non-trivial divisor: A non-trivial divisor of the number a is a natural number n with n!= 1 and n != a, so that a is multiple of n."  Would it not have been much simpler to just say "a(n)  is not prime"?

Comment: One line proof:  $a(n)= n^2 + 4n + 3 = (n+1)(n+3)$ so $(n+1)$ and $(n+3)$ which are neither equal to 1 or to $a(n)$ are the non-trivial divisors.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$a_n:= n^2 + 4n + 3 = (n+1)(n+3)\quad \text{ for }\quad n\in \mathbb N, n\geq 1\tag 1$$

So $$a_1 = (1+1)(1+3) = 2\cdot 4$$

Note also that $$n^2 + 6x + 8 = (n+2)(n + 4) = ((n + 1)+1)((n+1) + 3)= a_{n+1}$$

---

In the end, proof by induction can work, but it is not necessary.  Noting $(1)$ above, given any $n \in \mathbb N, n\ge 1$, $\quad a_n= n^2 + 4n + 3 = (n+1)(n+3)$ is, by definition, divisible by $n+1,$ and also by $n+3,$ each of which are non-trivial factors of $a_n$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

So now I can say (n+1)(n+3) = y * x, but I still do not see a way to express ((n+1)+1)((n+3)+1) that way.

Could you give me another hint?!